# Можно ли создать словарь из списка списков

Tags: python-3.x, list, словари

Уважаемы господа, хотелось бы узнать: есть ввод списка синонимов, нужно сделать из него словарь. Сперва вводится число пар синонимов, потом ввод текста:
4, Awful Terrible, Beautiful Pretty, Great Excellent, Generous Bountiful

я делаю из ввода список списков:

```
n = int(input())
sinon = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]
```

ежели дальше ввести одиночный `sinon_dict = {sinon[0][0]:sinon[0][1] for _ in sinon}`
то получится то что нужно: Awful: Terrible

И я никак ума не приложу, как это сделать циклом для каждого списка в общем списке. И можно ли это вообще сделать не понимаю.

Comment: `sinon_dict = {e[0]:r[1] for el in sinon}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто возьмите `dict(sinon)` - и там будет что нужно. Ну или можете сразу от вашего спискового сокращения взять `dict([...])`. Словарь умный, он понимает, что делать с коллекцией пар. Например:

```
print(dict(((1,2),(3,4))))
```

Вывод:

```
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```